# Conflict between arXiv, amsart, and amsrefs package

Tags: amsart, arxiv, amsrefs

A small example of LaTeX code producing the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsrefs}
\begin{document}
Citation: \cite{test}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{test}
A. Bates. Test Source.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

This arXiv compiler gives several pages of error including:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\safe@set ...nment \@nilgobble #1=0#2\relax \@nil 
l.7 Citation: \cite{test}
? 
! Emergency stop.
\safe@set ...nment \@nilgobble #1=0#2\relax \@nil 
l.7 Citation: \cite{test}
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Has anyone seen this before? And can you suggest a fix? (preferably using the same packages so that I don't need to reformat the document.)

Comment: I solved the problem by uploading my amsrefs.sty file.

Comment: the format of the bib item is not what is expected by `amsrefs`; it is the format expected from `bibtex`.  anyway, i'm glad the problem is solved.  voting to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was solved by making the required package file available, as noted by the op in a comment.